# Java 9 reactive flows: does one Subscriber belong to one Publisher

Tags: java, reactive-programming, java-9, reactive

I am wondering if a reactive flows Publisher can safely assume subscriptions belong to it **only** and call `java.util.concurrent.Flow.Subscriber#onComplete` on it, if the Publisher is going out of commission (e.g. being shut down). The code sample below demonstrates the dilemma (obviously it's just some synthetic code to demonstrate the question):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Flow;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TimePublisher implements Flow.Publisher<Long> {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Flow.Subscriber<? super Long>> subscribersList = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();


    private TimePublisher() {

    }

    public static TimePublisher newInstance() {
        TimePublisher timePublisher = new TimePublisher();
        timePublisher.startTickScheduler();

        return timePublisher;
    }

    private void startTickScheduler() {
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            // does not make too much sense: just for the sake of the example
            final long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            subscribersList.forEach(sub -> sub.onNext(currentTimeMillis));
        }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(Flow.Subscriber<? super Long> subscriber) {

        subscribersList.add(subscriber);

        subscriber.onSubscribe(new Flow.Subscription() {
            @Override
            public void request(long n) {
                // no-op in this sample
            }

            @Override
            public void cancel() {
                subscribersList.remove(subscriber);
            }
        });
    }

    public void stop() {
        // the publisher can be stopped from the outside: after that it will
        // definitely not emit any next items.
        scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();

        // QUESTION: can we assume that a Subscriber is subscribed to only this Publisher?
        // if it is subscribed to another publisher, the following is illegal, as onNext
        // could potentially be called by another Publisher...
        subscribersList.forEach(Flow.Subscriber::onComplete);

        subscribersList.clear();
    }
}
```

- when the `TimePublisher#stop` is called, this particular Publisher will absolutely not emit any `onNext` calls, hence calling `onComplete` seems to be a legitimate choice
- however, if the Subscriber is subscribed to another Publisher as well, then calling `onComplete` might be illegal, as the another Publisher could still be emitting items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `Subscriber` says

> The methods in this interface are invoked in strict sequential order **for each Flow.Subscription**.

`onComplete` in particular:

> Method invoked when it is known that no additional Subscriber method invocations will occur for a Subscription that is not already terminated by error, after which no other Subscriber methods are invoked **by the Subscription**. If this method throws an exception, resulting behavior is undefined.

So it's legal for other `Subscription`s to continue invoking methods.

`Flow` documentation says having multiple `Subscription`s in a `Subscriber` implementation is possible but not recommended:

> Because Subscriber method invocations for a given Flow.Subscription are strictly ordered, there is no need for these methods to use locks or volatiles unless a Subscriber maintains multiple Subscriptions (in which case it is better to instead define multiple Subscribers, each with its own Subscription).